# I get blackmailed by a person from which I have only the Etherium wallet adress

Tags: wallets, security, scam, transaction-trace, identity

I need help to identify a person that is blackmailing with what she thinks is compromising material, to send it to family, colleagues, etc etc, if I do not pay 300 € (as a start) to settle the issue.

Now I want to stop this, ideally, identify the person of this scam and maybe even charge legal actions. I do have the etherium wallet address - plus the transaction history, can this be used to make this scam stop?

Can anyone help me with this? Thanks a lot in advance. If possible, please refer me to someone who has experience with this.

M.

Answer (score 0):

sorry you are in this situation. Long story short yes, particularly, if that wallet address sends funds to a centralised exchange (either directly or after a few other transfers funds end up at a centralised exchange). You will need to firstly get law enforcement involved and obtain a court order to get the exchange to help you identify the person.

Comment: thanks for the swift reply. I will see if this person actually does what she threatens, then certainly I need to go for legal actions... I also have the list of transctions of this wallet address for the past 10 months or so, that was easy to get from Ethereum. Apart from law enforecement, are there no services that can help you with this?

Comment: There are, but dont waste your time, and money on them and dont worry about approaching law enforcement, they have seen it all before.